# TypeError: tag.indexOf is not a function in Messagebar Vue Component framwork7

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I am getting following error in Messagebar Vue Component:

**TypeError: tag.indexOf is not a function at messagebar.js:157:26.**

I am using **"framework7": "^8.3.0"**, **"framework7-vue": "^8.3.0",**  and **"vue": "^3.3.8"**

following is the code:

```
<f7-messagebar :placeholder="placeholder" ref="messagebar" :attachments-visible="attachmentsVisible" :sheet-visible="sheetVisible" v-show="loading==false">
    <f7-link icon-ios="f7:paperplane" icon-md="material:send" slot="inner-end" @click="sendMessage"></f7-link>
   <f7-messagebar-attachments>
       <f7-messagebar-attachment v-for="(image, index) in attachments" :key="index" :image="image" @attachment:delete="deleteAttachment(image)"></f7-messagebar-attachment>
       </f7-messagebar-attachments>
            <f7-messagebar-sheet>
                <f7-messagebar-sheet-image v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index" :image="image" :checked="attachments.indexOf(image) >= 0" @change="handleAttachment">
                </f7-messagebar-sheet-image>
            </f7-messagebar-sheet>
       </f7-messagebar>
</f7-messagebar>
```

when I comment the  line all works fine.